# Как убрать мини паузы между 2 видео при использовании Video View? Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, видео, videoview

Как можно убрать мини паузы между 2 видео при использовании Video View?
Есть видео, оно состоит из 3 кусков, которые воспроизводятся поочередно, но между ними есть 1-1.5 секунды зависания, а нужно, чтобы видео проигрывалось цельно без этих пауз.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо выполнить предподготовку видео файлов. Для этого можно использовать класс MediaPlayer и метод [MediaPlayer#prepareAsync](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#prepareAsync()). Используя [MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnPreparedListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener)) можно узнать, когда закончилась загрузка файла и его можно использовать.

Т.е. перед проигрыванием видео вы создаёте 3 объекта(по одному на каждый видео файл), устанавливаете слушатель на [OnPreparedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)), ещё один слушатель устанавливаете на [OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setOnCompletionListener(android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener))(для смены проигрываемых файлов) и начинаете проигрывать видео ряд.

Последний шаг с `OnCompletionListener` может быть лишним, если есть возможность использовать API 16 и выше для использования [следующего метода](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setNextMediaPlayer(android.media.MediaPlayer)). В этом случае сама система будет переключаться между файлами после их окончания.